# What could prevent an NSTableView from being sortable?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsmutabledictionary, nsarraycontroller

I've inherited a cocoa project that has an NSTableView in it, and clicking on the column headers does not sort the view, but I want the columns to be sortable. I am using cocoa bindings.

Things I've tried to make the columns sortable:

- Make sure that 'creates sort descriptor' is checked on the column attributes.
- Verify that the proper keys are added in the ArrayController attributes (the Array is arranging NSMutableDictionaries. Maybe this is causing problems?)
- Verify that the Sort Key of the column is correct ("name") and the Selector is correct ("compare:")

What else could be causing the columns to not sort when I click the header?

Comment: Actually, of the things you mentioned above, only the "creates sort descriptor" being checked is necessary. I've made lots of tables and don't usually add keys to the controller's attributes or have any sort keys in the column info, and they still sort. It would be helpful if you could give more info on the structure of the data that's bound to the array controller.

Comment: Have you bound anything to sortDescriptors on the array controller?